# Quickly prove monotonicity of an integral function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How can one quickly show that the function
$$f(x) = e^{x^2/2}\int_x^{+\infty} e^{-s^2/2} ds$$
is monotonically decreasing for every $x \in \mathbb R$?

Differentiating I don't seem to get an easy inequality to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Using [Logarithmic derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_derivative) you get:

$$\frac{f^\prime(x)}{f(x)} = xe^{-x^2/2} - \frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\int_x^{+\infty} e^{-s^2/2} ds} = e^{-x^2/2}\left(x - \frac{1}{\int_x^{+\infty} e^{-s^2/2} ds}\right).$$

As $f(x)>0$ on $\mathbb R$, you're left to prove that

$$x \int_x^{+\infty} e^{-s^2/2} ds < 1.$$

This is clear for $x \le 0$. And for $x > 0$ you have

$$x \int_x^{+\infty} e^{-s^2/2} ds \le \int_x^{+\infty} se^{-s^2/2} ds = e^{-x^2/2} < 1$$